# 2d animation armature problems

Tags: animation, armature, grease-pencil

When i try to pose my armature everything warps and some parts do not move how do i fix this?[image: warped armature]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i need it to be rigid when i move it and not get all melty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you parent a GP object to an armature with automatic weight, every deforming bone creates a vertex group in the GP object with the same name.

If you select the GP and go to weight paint mode you can select every vertex group, one by one, and see its weight assignements (blue = 0.0, cyan = some weight, green = 0.5, orange lot of weight, red = 1.0 full weight).

If you want to have i.e. the head rigid, you have to do two things:

1. in edit mode select all vertices of the head, select the head vertex group, go down to the weight slider, take it to 1.0 and click the "Assign" button.
2. select all the others vertex groups one by one and click the "Remove" button.

Do the same for the rest of the character parts.

[image]

Comment: Thank you it worked.